# Using if / else if function to do different things depending on the option chosen inside a select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, method-call

I would like to have a dropdown select/option menu that does different things depending on which option you choose.

My select looks like this:

```
<div class="controls">
    <select id="classFilter">
        <option value="0" selected>All</option>
        <option value="1">Scion</option>
        <option value="2">Marauder</option>
        <option value="3">Ranger</option>
        <option value="4">Witch</option>
        <option value="5">Duelist</option>
        <option value="6">Templar</option>
        <option value="7">Shadow</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And here's the `if` / `else if` I'm trying to use:

```
$("#classFilter").change(function () {
    if ($('#classFilter option[value="0"]')) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="1"]')) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="2"]')) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="3"]')) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="4"]')) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="5"]')) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="6"]')) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="7"]')) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }
});
```

I've tried using `.val()` but it didn't work either. While switching the options the code always jumps into the first `if` no matter if I change the value.

Another problem is that I'm trying to call a function inside these if statements, but it doesn't seem to work either. Is it not possible to call a function for `select`?

```
    function hardcoreTop100() {
        $("#IHC").click(function () {
            $.getJSON("http://api.pathofexile.com/ladders/Hardcore?limit=100&callback=?", function (result) {

                $.each(result["entries"], function (index, value) {

                    if (value.dead === true) {
                        $("#tdRanking").append(
                            "<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + value.rank + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.account.name + "</td>"
                            + "<td id=\"dead\">" + value.character.name + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.character.level + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.character.experience + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.character.class + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.account.challenges.total + "</td>"
                            + "<td class=\"offline\">" + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>" + "<br/>");
                    }

                    else if (value.online === true) {
                        $("#tdRanking").append(
                            "<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + value.rank + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.account.name + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.character.name + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.character.level + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.character.experience + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.character.class + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.account.challenges.total + "</td>"
                            + "<td class=\"online\">" + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>" + "<br/>");
                    }

                    else {
                        $("#tdRanking").append(
                            "<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + value.rank + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.account.name + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.character.name + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.character.level + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.character.experience + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.character.class + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + value.account.challenges.total + "</td>"
                            + "<td class=\"offline\">" + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>" + "<br/>");
                    }
                });
            });

            $("td").remove("td");
            $("tr:empty").remove();

        });
    }
```

Comment: why would you use 7 different `if` statements ? doesn't look 'right'

Comment: instead of check for each and every option you can just get selected index value and add your condition using it.. check https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp

Comment: I suppose you're not actually just logging the selected value, please show the real code, this particular case can be done without any `if` at all, just by logging the value of the select element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem being that you are not checking for `selected` value. I would suggest to use [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) instead of if else here like following.

```js
$("#classFilter").change(function () {
  switch(this.value) {
    case "0" : console.log(this.value); break;
    case "1" : console.log(this.value); break;
    case "2" : console.log(this.value); break;
    case "3" : console.log(this.value); break;
    case "4" : console.log(this.value); break;
    case "5" : console.log(this.value); break;
    case "6" : console.log(this.value); break;
    case "7" : console.log(this.value); break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
    <select id="classFilter">
        <option value="0" selected>All</option>
        <option value="1">Scion</option>
        <option value="2">Marauder</option>
        <option value="3">Ranger</option>
        <option value="4">Witch</option>
        <option value="5">Duelist</option>
        <option value="6">Templar</option>
        <option value="7">Shadow</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Do you know how I can call a function inside the cases? When I try to call one it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Lapahn - Can you please share your effort and I can help you with it. Also, note that `console.log` is a function only which is being called here. Just add any function statement before break statement for the case and that should work.

Comment: I've added the question and code on the bottom. I'm trying to call a function inside on of the cases. Later on I want to have a function that only shows me the specific classes from the game. So when I choose "Ranger" it should only show Rangers etc.

Comment: @Lapahn - In the function you are binding a click event to an element. Can you add your html as well. Also, try to add some logs in your function and see the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to go that route, you also need to check that the option with said value is `:selected`, and that the length of the collection is not 0:

```js
$("#classFilter").change(function () {
    if ($('#classFilter option[value="0"]:selected').length !== 0) {
        console.log('option 0');
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="1"]:selected').length !== 0) {
        console.log('option 1');
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="2"]:selected').length !== 0) {
        console.log('option 2');
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="3"]:selected').length !== 0) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="4"]:selected').length !== 0) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="5"]:selected').length !== 0) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="6"]:selected').length !== 0) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    else if ($('#classFilter option[value="7"]:selected').length !== 0) {
        console.log(this.value);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
    <select id="classFilter">
        <option value="0" selected>All</option>
        <option value="1">Scion</option>
        <option value="2">Marauder</option>
        <option value="3">Ranger</option>
        <option value="4">Witch</option>
        <option value="5">Duelist</option>
        <option value="6">Templar</option>
        <option value="7">Shadow</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

But you might find it easier to use an object (indexed by value) of functions instead:

```js
const optionFns = {
  0: () => console.log('default option!'),
  1: () => console.log('you chose value 1!'),
  2: () => console.log('Marauder!'),
  3: () => console.log('Ranger...'),
}

$("#classFilter").change(function () {
  const value = $('#classFilter option:selected').val();
  optionFns[value]();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
    <select id="classFilter">
        <option value="0" selected>All</option>
        <option value="1">Scion</option>
        <option value="2">Marauder</option>
        <option value="3">Ranger</option>
        <option value="4">Witch</option>
        <option value="5">Duelist</option>
        <option value="6">Templar</option>
        <option value="7">Shadow</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you mean to use [`is(":selected")`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) or access `.length`. `jQuery()` always returns an object even if the selector doesn't match, and objects are always truthy

Comment: The code is still jumping inside the first if statement and then jumps out no matter which option I choose.

Comment: Also you can get the value of a select element directly `$('#classFilter').val()`  op just had the same mistake you made and tested against an object.

Comment: @Lapahn See edit, you also need to check the `length` of the collection if you do that sort of repetitive if/else sort of thing (but I'd prefer to use the object of functions, whose keys correspond to option values, as in the second code)

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks, that works! How would I go with calling a function inside the const? For example `3: () => hardcoreTop100()`

Comment: Put your `hardcoreTop100` *as the function on `3` itself*. Or `3: hardcoreTop100`

Answer (score 1):

You can read the value of select box and then compare it in if else block. See below code

```js
$("#classFilter").change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value=="0") {
        console.log(value);
       } else if(value=="0") {
        console.log(value);
       } else if(value=="1") {
        console.log(value);
       } else if(value=="2") {
        console.log(value);
       } else if(value=="3") {
        console.log(value);
       } else if(value=="4") {
        console.log(value);
       } else if(value=="5") {
        console.log(value);
       } else if(value=="6") {
        console.log(value);
       } else if(value=="7") {
        console.log(value);
       }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
    <select id="classFilter">
        <option value="0" selected>All</option>
        <option value="1">Scion</option>
        <option value="2">Marauder</option>
        <option value="3">Ranger</option>
        <option value="4">Witch</option>
        <option value="5">Duelist</option>
        <option value="6">Templar</option>
        <option value="7">Shadow</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// We can get the selected value from the select itsself, not the options.
const selected_class = $("#classSelection").val();
// A function we want to use differently depending on what was selected.
const create_class = function( attr_str, attr_con, attr_int ) {
  // create a new character with these stats.
  return 'creating new class with stats: ' + attr_str + '|' + attr_con + '|' + attr_int;
};
// Might as well use an object to store the function calls instead of a list of if/else statements. It's easier to add extra options this way.
const class_functions = {
  all: function() {
    // create one of each class
  },
  duelist: function() {
    return create_class( 18, 14, 8 );
  },
  marauder: function() {
    return create_class( 20, 16, 4 );
  },
  ranger: function() {
    return create_class( 14, 14, 12 );
  },
  scion: function() {
    return create_class( 12, 20, 10 );
  },
  shadow: function() {
    return create_class( 12, 12, 16 );
  },
  templar: function() {
    return create_class( 16, 12, 14 );
  },
  witch: function() {
    return create_class( 8, 8, 20 );
  }
};
// Create the selected class. Scion is selected in the dropdown.
const character = class_functions[ selected_class ]();
console.log( character );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="classSelection">
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="scion" selected>Scion</option>
  <option value="marauder">Marauder</option>
  <option value="ranger">Ranger</option>
  <option value="witch">Witch</option>
  <option value="duelist">Duelist</option>
  <option value="templar">Templar</option>
  <option value="shadow">Shadow</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with selected attribute that you used inside the option tag.

```
<select id="classFilter">
   <option value="0"  selected="selected">All</option>
   <option value="1">Scion</option>
   <option value="2">Marauder</option>
   <option value="3">Ranger</option>
   <option value="4">Witch</option>
   <option value="5">Duelist</option>
   <option value="6">Templar</option>
   <option value="7">Shadow</option>
</select>
```

Follow this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) for further details

This will work for your JavaScript function.

```
$("select#classFilter").on('change', function(e){
   console.log($("select#classFilter").val());
});
```